# RCP nattable groupBy column for 55,000+ data performance

Tags: java, sorting, filtering, rcp, nattable

Using RCP Framework, I have a nattable with about 30 columns and 55,000+ rows of data. When I bring up the group by column feature built into the Nattable, the whole program freezes since there is so much data. Is there a way to be able to continue to use those groupBy feature without having performance issues? Also, filtering the columns the performance has a little bit of lag with about a 4-5second return.

Currently using Nattable version 1.5

Comment: Which version of NatTable? The recent versions do not show such heavy performance issues in my experience.

Comment: Nattable Version 1.5.

Comment: Try with a newer version to see if the performance issue persists.